# meteor specify working directory in container

Tags: meteor, containers, singularity-container

I'm trying to install a meteor application inside a container (singularity), but when I start the application it wants to write to a read only part of the image. Is it possible to specify a working directory different from the application directory? Or, start the application from a writeable directory and point to the applications install directory?

```
  .../promise_server.js:165 throw error; 
  Error: EROFS, mkdir '/usr/local/mindcontrol/.meteor/local'
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the application to /usr/local yourself? Maybe you can install it to another directory inside the container, e.g. /mindcontrol.

Then you can mount a directory for which you have write-permissions (your home for example):

`singularity exec --bind <some_dir>:/mindcontrol <container.img> <command>`